# Should $\bigcap F \in F$ for all filters?

Tags: set-theory, filters

Given a nonempty set $U$, Define a set $F$ to be a filter on $U$ if $F \subseteq P(I), \forall A \in F , A \subseteq B \subseteq U \implies B \in F , \forall A,B \in F (A \cap B \in F), \emptyset \notin F.$
Even for uncountably infinite set $U$, can I guarantee that $\bigcap F \in F$ for any filter $F$ on $U$? If $F$ has countably many elements, I can guarantee it by induction, but if $F$ has a cardinality larger than $\aleph_0$ , I can't think of the proof of $\bigcap F \in F$.

Comment: In the study of ultrafilters (assuming Choice), it's actually very important that $\bigcap F = \emptyset \not\in F$ for most ultrafilters over a set, so we should be glad $\bigcap F \in F$ is not generally true.

Comment: Oh.. I'm trying to prove that if a fliter $D$ is a maximal filter on $U$, it is an ultrafilter. My textbook defines an ultrafilter as: a fliter $F$ is an ultrafilter if for any $A \subseteq U$, either $A \in F$ or $U-A \in F$. Can you give me a hint for that?

Comment: Another usual part of the def'n of a filter $F$ on $U$ is that $U\in F, $ equivalently that $F$ is not empty.

Answer (score 5):

In general it is not true that $\bigcap F\in F$, even when $F$ and $U$ are both countable. For example, let $F=\{\Bbb N\setminus A:A\text{ is finite}\}$, the *cofinite filter* on $\Bbb N$; then $F$ is countably infinite, but clearly $\bigcap F=\varnothing$.

Induction can only prove that the intersection of any finite subset of $F$ is in $F$; it cannot prove that the intersection of infinitely many members of $F$ is in $F$.

Comment: Oh.. I'm trying to prove that if a fliter $D$ is a maximal filter on $U$, it is an ultrafilter. My textbook defines an ultrafilter as: a fliter $F$ is an ultrafilter if for any $A \subseteq U$, either $A \in F$ or $U-A \in F$. Can you give me a hint for that?

Comment: @John.P: Show that if $F$ is a filter on $U$, and $A\subseteq U$, then either $A\cap E\ne\varnothing$ for every $E\in F$, or $(U\setminus A)\cap E\ne\varnothing$ for every $E\in F$ (or both). Use this to show that if $U$ is maximal, then $U$ is an ultrafilter, and if $U$ is not maximal, then $U$ is not an ultrafilter.